# How do I start building a simple Q&A study web app using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to build a simple Question and answer web application using Ruby on Rails. 
This is for the purpose of an interactive Q&A study tool that I want to create for students. 
It has basic components:

1. Question (I have a list of exam revision questions that will show up one question at a time)
2. A 'Contribute my answer' box where students can answer the question.
3. A facebook style 'comment' section, where students can view the answers that others have contributed.
4. Button "Go to next question" that goes to a randomised question in my list.

This project is my way to learn Ruby on Rails, coming from a non-programming background, can you help guide me to the right resources or examples that I can learn from? 
Guidance on the basic framework and an overview of the best steps to take would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
sz03

Comment: nothing about that is simple if you do not know anything about programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginer with RoR you should start with a ruby tutorial then with a RoR tutorial. I suggest you this one : http://ruby.railstutorial.org

Then you can use Surveyvor to create your app : https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor
or SMERF https://github.com/springbok/smerf

For CSS and Javascript, you can start with bootstrap : http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: Thankyou Ludovic, Surveyvor was what I was looking for. Do you know if there any other gems and other tools that are specifically for Q&A style apps?

Comment: In my opinion, Surveyvor is the best but I edited my answer with others gems.

Comment: @sz03 Don't forget to accept the correct answer for next people !